# SqlDataReader Read method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I am trying to retrieve column values from database here is my code

```
protected void LoadProfile()
{
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        cmdProfile = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Father, Gender, UserName, City, Country, Department, Year, Degree, JobTittle, Organization, JobCity, JobCountry, JobTittle FROM UserProfile WHERE UserName=@UserName", conn);

        cmdProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);

        conn.Open();

        reader = cmdProfile.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            labelName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
            txtBoxFather.Text = reader["Father"].ToString();
            TextBoxGender.Text = reader["Gender"].ToString();
            TextBoxAge.Text = "";
            TextBoxCity.Text = reader["City"].ToString();
            TextBoxCountry.Text = reader["Country"].ToString();
            TextBoxDepartment.Text = reader["Department"].ToString();
            TextBoxDegree.Text = reader["Degree"].ToString();
            TextBoxYear.Text = reader["Year"].ToString();
            TextBoxJobTittle.Text = reader["JobTittle"].ToString();
            TextBoxJobCity.Text = reader["JobCity"].ToString();
            TextBoxJobCountry.Text = reader["JobCountry"].ToString();
            TextBoxOrganization.Text = reader["Organization"].ToString();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

But it is not retrieving  anything from database.

Actually I am taking `userName` parameter as query string from different page using this line

```
 userName = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
```

When I put break points the control is not going forward after this line

```
if (reader.Read())
```

This is the page from where I am taking query string. .

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridAllAlumni" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="GridAllAlumni_ItemCommand">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server"
                            Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'
                            PostBackUrl='<%#"~/Profile/Profile.aspx?Name="+Eval("Name") %>'/>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Where am I getting wrong?

Your help will be appreciated. Thanx

Comment: What error? Post the stacktrace / exception.

Comment: try if(reader.HasRows()) -> reader.Read()

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih: No errors but the textboxes remains empty

Comment: Does the query work if you execute it directly at the DB server? is this possibly simply because the query returns zero rows? perhaps due to case sensitivity on the `UserName=@UserName` check? Is `userName` what you *expect* it to be?

Comment: btw, it won't *stop it working*, but it would be a really good idea to a: separate the UI and data access, and b: use `using` aggressively (all of `conn`, `cmdProfile` and `reader` are `IDisposable`, and should make use of `using` blocks)

Comment: @Jonesy: I checked in sql server there are rows with that userName but it's not showing

Comment: @user2517610 have you checked that `userName` is what you *expected* it to be, and that it matches the data in the DB?

Comment: well, are you sure the userName variable is the same as the one you supplied in sql server when it gets added?

Comment: Actually i am trying to retrieve the profile of user from gridview on diffrent page after clicking on the link in gridview. . .it works properly for 1 record but not working for other records in the same gridview

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes it matches the data in the DB. . it works fine for only one record but for others it shows nothing. . same gridview same query but not the same result :(

Comment: are you updating the right textboxes?  Try adding an ORDER BY in the query then seeing what the one textbox that is working displays.  does it display the last record?

Comment: @Jonesy: Just trying to retrive fields in textbox from database

Comment: I think your end goal is unclear

Answer (score 1):

It is `while(reader.Read())` It is not looping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I basically changed `@UserName` to `:UserName` in the query and removed the `@` in the `cmdProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);`. It worked for me. But, I may be wrong. So, feel free to correct me.

```
protected void LoadProfile()
{
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        cmdProfile = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Father, Gender, UserName, City, Country, Department, Year, Degree, JobTittle, Organization, JobCity, JobCountry, JobTittle FROM UserProfile WHERE UserName=:UserName", conn);

        cmdProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", userName);

        conn.Open();

        reader = cmdProfile.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            labelName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
            txtBoxFather.Text = reader["Father"].ToString();
            TextBoxGender.Text = reader["Gender"].ToString();
            TextBoxAge.Text = "";
            TextBoxCity.Text = reader["City"].ToString();
            TextBoxCountry.Text = reader["Country"].ToString();
            TextBoxDepartment.Text = reader["Department"].ToString();
            TextBoxDegree.Text = reader["Degree"].ToString();
            TextBoxYear.Text = reader["Year"].ToString();
            TextBoxJobTittle.Text = reader["JobTittle"].ToString();
            TextBoxJobCity.Text = reader["JobCity"].ToString();
            TextBoxJobCountry.Text = reader["JobCountry"].ToString();
            TextBoxOrganization.Text = reader["Organization"].ToString();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```